# SQL compilation error: syntax error line 6 at position 75 unexpected 'on'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on a long query that has multiple joins, and I am getting this error numerous times, can someone please assist? I went through every single solution online, but it doesn't seem to be my case. Below is an example where I am getting this "SQL compilation error: syntax error line 6 at position 75 unexpected 'on'"

```
select
    clmt.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY,
    dlexp.LOSS_EXPOSURE_NATURAL_KEY,
    min(rtncall.RETURNED_CALL_DATE_TIME_KEY) MIN_RETURN_CALL_DATE_TIME_KEY
from 
    PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_CLAIMANT clmt
left join 
    PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_CLAIM_CONTACT_RETURN_CALL rtncall on clmt.CLAIM_CONTACT_KEY = rtncall.CLAIM_CONTACT_KEY 
left join 
    PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_LOSS_EXPOSURE dlexp on clmt.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY = dlexp.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY 
where 
    rtncall.RETURNED_CALL_STATUS_CODE = 'CONTACTED'
    and dlexp.CURRENT_RECORD_IND = 'Y' 
group by 
    clmt.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY, dlexp.LOSS_EXPOSURE_NATURAL_KEY
```

Non-formatted code here:

```
select
clmt.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY
,dlexp.LOSS_EXPOSURE_NATURAL_KEY
,min(rtncall.RETURNED_CALL_DATE_TIME_KEY) MIN_RETURN_CALL_DATE_TIME_KEY
from PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_CLAIMANT clmt
left join PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_CLAIM_CONTACT_RETURN_CALL rtncall on clmt.CLAIM_CONTACT_KEY = rtncall.CLAIM_CONTACT_KEY 
left join PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_LOSS_EXPOSURE as dlexp on clmt.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY = dlexp.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY 
where rtncall.RETURNED_CALL_STATUS_CODE = 'CONTACTED'
and dlexp.CURRENT_RECORD_IND = 'Y' 
group by 
clmt.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY
,dlexp.LOSS_EXPOSURE_NATURAL_KEY
```

How to solve this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

I tried some solutions from the snowflake community but can't find why this keeps happening.

Comment: Are you missing an `as`?  `PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_CLAIM_CONTACT_RETURN_CALL as rtncall` ?

Comment: Hi @StephenC, thanks for the help but I don't think that's what is causing the error. Snowflake recognizes the table name alias with/without an 'as'

Comment: @marc_s, idea of formatting the code was not so brilliant, since "syntax error line 6 at position 75 unexpected 'on'" is now useless

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky Agreed! I added the non-formatted code again. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
clmt.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY
,dlexp.LOSS_EXPOSURE_NATURAL_KEY
,min(rtncall.RETURNED_CALL_DATE_TIME_KEY) MIN_RETURN_CALL_DATE_TIME_KEY
from PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_CLAIMANT clmt
left join PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_CLAIM_CONTACT_RETURN_CAL
rtncall on clmt.CLAIM_CONTACT_KEY = rtncall.CLAIM_CONTACT_KEY 
left join PNC_PSA_DB.KEDW_KSG_LOSS_CDC.D_LOSS_EXPOSURE dlexp on
clmt.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY = dlexp.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY 
where rtncall.RETURNED_CALL_STATUS_CODE = 'CONTACTED'
and dlexp.CURRENT_RECORD_IND = 'Y' 
group by 
clmt.CLAIMANT_NATURAL_KEY
,dlexp.LOSS_EXPOSURE_NATURAL_KEY;
```

This code works as is and is syntactically right.